# Limiting the number of XML items to parse in php that match a specific value

Tags: php, xml, if-statement, xml-parsing

The PHP I have right now is only half working and it is a little clunky. I'm looking to display the 3 most recent press releases from an XML feed that match a specific value type. What I have right now is only looking at the first three items, and just echoing the ones that match the value. I'm also pretty sure `DOM` object is not the best approach here, but had issues getting `xparse` to work properly. Some help with the logic would be greatly appreciated.

```
//create new document object
$dom_object = new DOMDocument();
//load xml file
$dom_object->load("http://cws.huginonline.com/A/138060/releases_999_all.xml");
$cnt = 0;

foreach ($dom_object->getElementsByTagName('press_release') as $node) {
    if($cnt == 3 ) {
        break;
    }

    $valueID = $node->getAttribute('id'); 
    $valueType = $node->getAttribute('type'); 

    $headline = $dom_object->getElementsByTagName("headline");
    $headlineContent  = $headline->item(0)->nodeValue;

    $releaseDate = $dom_object->getElementsByTagName("published");
    $valueDate = $releaseDate->item(0)->getAttribute('date'); 

    $cnt++;

    if ($valueType == 5) {
        echo "<div class=\"newsListItem\"> <p> $valueDate </p> <h4>$headlineContent</h4><p></p></div>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

DOM has the ability to execute Xpath expression on the XML tree to fetch nodes and scalar values. Use `DOMXpath::evaluate()` - not just the DOM methods.

But the "3 most recent" is not a filter. It is a sort with a limit. You will have to read each item and keep the 3 "newest" or read all of them into a list, sort it and get the first 3 from the list.

You can do this in PHP or using XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

this did the trick...

```
if ($valueType == 5)
    {   
        if ($printCount < 3) {
         echo "...";
         $printCount++;
        }

    }
```